# How do I lock Filter but not Filter View?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a large number of people looking at my spreadsheet and I constantly get the problem of someone using filter instead of filterview which is a problem and highly annoying. I make announcements in emails, send notifications and even have a row colored in red saying "DO NOT USE FILTER, USE FILTER VIEW" but still I get people using filter.

I've tried protecting that row which prevents the user from using filter but it also prevents the user from using filter view as well.

How can I lock filter and not filter view?

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community user 14 times.

Answer (score 0):

Add people as viewers, not as editors or protect the entire sheet not only one row.

Answer (score -2):

This can happen with arrayformulas, especially if their range isn't the entire sheet. A way around it is to put your formulas in row 1 *and keep it blank*

example of bad:

> A1: Date
>
> A2: arrayformula(func(B2:B))

This will work with filter views (Protect and Hide Row 1):

> A1: =arrayformula(if(row(B:B)=1,,if(row(B:B)=2,"Date",func(B:B))))

Side Bonus: This method prevents issues where deleted rows mess up the R1C1 notation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).